# TF1 to TF2 migration

Tags: python, keras, migration, tensorflow2.0, placeholder

Hello I am new to tensorflow and I am working on a code that I would like to migrate from tensorflow 1 to 2. I have this line of code:

```
x1 = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [], name="x1")
```

As mentioned in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/placeholder, I should use `keras.Input`. But even when specifying the shape, I can't have the same tensor as with compat.v1:

```
x2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.float32, name="x2")
```

To check the shape I use `tf.shape(x1)` or `tf.shape(x2)`, but the shapes are not the same. Could anyone explain to me how to have, in TF2, the same shape as in TF1 ?
Thanks and regards

Comment: What do you mean exactly the shapes are not the same? What shapes are they?

Comment: Sorry I should have written that in my question, ```x1``` has shape ```(0,)```whereas ```x2``` has shape ```(1,)```.

Comment: mmm ok and why do you need to pass empty shapes? That would make no sense to me.

Comment: I don't know, for now I am just in the process of understand deeply and migrate a code from TF1 to TF2. In the original code, there is a variable defined as ```x1```, and I don't know for now its role lol.